# in plotly dash, how do i explicitly set the base tag inside the HTML head?

Tags: html, plotly-dash

In Plotly dash, how do I explicitly set the base tag inside the HTML head?

So that after running the app, I'll get the following g HTML:

````
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/my/base/url">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Dash HTML components go here -->
    </body>
</html>```
````